# is it possible to access the values of enum?

Tags: java, oop, enums

I have this code

```
    enum check
{
   STUDENT ("Sireee"), ID (12354), YEAR ("1st Year"), DEP("College of Computer Studies");
   private String year;
   private String student;
   private String dep;
   private int id;
 // some Constructor here
```

my problem is I dont know how to get the values of of STUDENT, ID, YEAR, and DEP in the main class. how to be able to get this values? 
[image]

and the result is [image]

my **EXPECTED OUTPUT ** is

Sireee

12345

1st Year

College of Computer Studies

Comment: This does not look like an appropriate use case for an enum -- it looks like an appropriate use case for a class.

Comment: You are using `enum` the wrong way. It is not used to maintain the state like a `class`. Define a class named `Student` that holds `name`, `id`, `year` and `dep`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `enum` the wrong way. In your case, it is preferable to use a `class`

`Student.java`

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String year; // int is prefered. since you are using string I used it.
    private Department dep; // demonstrating use of enum

    // getters and setters
}
```

Now, let's see how we can use `enum`

`Department.java`

```
public enum Department {

    CSE("Computer Science Engineering"),
    MEC("Mechanical Engineering")

    private String name;

    Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

If you wish to display the values now, lets create two students and display the values

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setName("John Wick");
        s1.setId(1);
        s1.setYear("1st Year");
        s1.setDepartment(Department.CSE);

        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setName("Will Smith");
        s2.setId(2);
        s2.setYear("2nd Year");
        s2.setDepartment(Department.MEC);

        System.out.println(s1.getName() + " department is " + s1.getDepartment().getName());
        System.out.println(s2.getName() + " department is " + s2.getDepartment().getName());
    }
}
```

`Output`:

```
John Wick department is Computer Science Engineering
Will Smith department is Mechanical Engineering
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir <3 tho I also tried different ways and it worked thank you for you insights

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was able to solved this problem thanks to all your answers and I did tried some experiments and I was amazed that it really works <3  [image]